# How to count how many entries in a column are numeric using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, count, alphanumeric

I am trying to count how many entries are in a column that are both numeric and fulfill other conditions. I understand how that script is meant to look in SQL:

```
    SELECT COUNT(ingredients)
    FROM data.pie
    WHERE description LIKE 'cherry'
      AND is.numeric(price) = true
```

But I'm not sure how to translate that into a PostgreSQL script. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are there any prices that are NOT numeric?

Comment: "fourteen dollars"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative to the one shown by Tim is to create a function ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_numeric(val VARCHAR) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE x NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    x = val::NUMERIC;
    RETURN TRUE;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN    
    RETURN FALSE;
END;
$$
STRICT
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

.. that can be used like this:

```
db=# SELECT is_numeric('foo'), is_numeric('1'), is_numeric('1.39');
 is_numeric | is_numeric | is_numeric 
------------+------------+------------
 f          | t          | t
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: If there's room for Tim, then there's also room for Jim +1.

Comment: How would I be able to use the function in a WHERE clause?

Comment: @Alokin `SELECT * FROM data.pie WHERE is_numeric(price)`

Comment: I can run it as a stand alone in a select line, but when I move it to the WHERE line I get the error
ERROR: function is_numeric(numeric) does not exist

Comment: @Alokin you have to create the function first. Open a connection to your postgres and execute the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement I wrote on my answer. If it works in the SELECT clause, it must work in the WHERE clause as well

Comment: @Alokin Keep in mind that this function expects a `varchar` as parameter. If you want to pass a `numeric` value, as your error message suggests, you have to cast it: `SELECT * FROM data.pie WHERE is_numeric(price::varchar)`. Although I'm not sure if it makes much sense for your use case :D

Comment: Yup, that did it. I'm sorry, I should have specified earlier that the stuff in the columns might not be numeric. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your current query, slightly modified, should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(ingredients)
FROM data.pie
WHERE
    description LIKE 'cherry' AND
    price ~ '^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$';
```

Comment: I've tried running that, and I get an error around the tilda that says:
ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric ~ unknown

HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type cast.

Does that means it doesn't recognize the tilda? Or the conditions after it?

Comment: Is your `price` column `text`?  Note that ideally prices should be stored in a numeric type column.

Comment: You're right. Using Jim's entry, I have to make this
        price::varchar ~ '^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$'
to get it to run.

Comment: Then what type is `price`?  I mean, your question only makes much sense if `price` _isn't_ numeric.  In any case, as mentioned above you should store prices in a numeric column.

Comment: 'price' is labeled as text, but there could be some numerics in it, so I'm doing this count to find out how many.